# Conditionally ignoring the last word

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone help with this please? (also posted on RegexBuddy forum)

I have this relatively large (autogenerated) regular expression (listed in full at the bottom) and there are number of repeated fragments using this fragment:-

```
# Add words to word list
(?<_KC1>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))
```

this is designed to 'scoop up' words and text between the more well-known fragments. These captures are all aggregated later in code to provide a list of words within the overall match.

The problem I have is the first of the alternate sections, namely this:

```
    # Pair of Strike prices
    (?<Strike>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/(?<Strike2>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)

    # Add to Word List (but not 'x' as last word) !!!!!!!!!!!! This is what needs changing
    (?<_KC3>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

    # Cross price
    (?:x[ \t]?-?(?<Cross>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x?)?
```

As you can see the "Cross Price" always starts with an 'x', so what I need is a pattern as similar as possible to the first fragment I mentioned but to ignore the last word if it happens to be 'x'.
There are two further complications:
1) The "Cross Price" itself is optional
2) 'x' itself can match the "Futures Expiry Date" as a Reuters date code.

I have tried negative lookbehinds and so on but no matter what I do I mess something else up. I believe the answer might lie in If-Then-Else conditionals but I'm not sure.

As an example:-

**WTI AMERICAN : Jun12 110.00/140.00 [1x2] Call Spread x 102.50 350 - 365**

The "Pair of Strike prices" is returning "**110.00/140.00**" as expected

But the Word List is extracting " **[1x2] Call Spread x** "
and the "**102.50**" which should have been the "Cross Price" is now being matched later in the expression as the "Bid" part of the "Bid/Offer Spread".

Any help on this gratefully received

Cheers
Simon

```
# Match this group (optional)
(?:

    # Match one of the product symbols or their aliases
    \b(?<ProductSymbol>CL|Brent|GasOil|WTI|LO|BRT)\b

    # Add words to word list
    (?<_KC1>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

    # Skip over whitespace plus any of these characters [:]
    [ \t:]+
)?

# Futures expiry date
(?<=[ \t]|'|^)(?<FuturesExpiryPeriod>(?<_MY>(?<_MYP>(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?))[ \t]?(?<_MYY>(?:20)?\d\d))|(?<_CE>Cal-?(?<_CEY>(?:20)?\d\d))|(?<_QF>Q(?:uarter)?(?<_QFP>1|2|3|4)[ \t]*(?<_QFY>(?:20)?\d\d))|(?<_QL>(?<_QLP>1|2|3|4)[ \t]*Q(?:uarter)?[ \t]*(?<_QLY>(?:20)?\d\d))|(?<_HY>(?<_HYP>1|2)[ \t]*H(?:alf)?[ \t]*(?<_HYY>(?:20)?\d\d))|(?<_ER>(?<_ERP>[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])(?<_ERY>\d{0,2}))[ \t]*)

# Skip over whitespace
[ \t]+

# Add words to word list
(?<_KC2>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

# Match one of the following choices (in order):
(?:
    (?: # First choice

        # Pair of Strike prices
        (?<Strike>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/(?<Strike2>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)

        # Add to Word List (but not 'x' as last word) !!!!!!!!!!!! This is what needs changing
        (?<_KC3>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

        # Cross price
        (?:x[ \t]?-?(?<Cross>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x?)?
    )
    |
    (?: # Second choice

        # Cross price
        (?:x[ \t]?-?(?<Cross>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x?)

        # Add words to word list
        (?<_KC4>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

        # Pair of Strike prices
        (?<Strike>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/(?<Strike2>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?
    )
    |
    (?: # Third choice

        # Single Strike price
        (?<Strike>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)

        # Add to Word List (but not 'x' as last word) !!!!!!!!!!!! This is what needs changing
        (?<_KC5>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

        # Cross price
        (?:x[ \t]?-?(?<Cross>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x?)?
    )
    |
    (?: # Fourth choice

        # Cross price
        (?:x[ \t]?-?(?<Cross>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)x?)

        # Add words to word list
        (?<_KC6>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

        # Single Strike price
        (?<Strike>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?
    )
)

# Add words to word list
(?<_KC7>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

# Skip over whitespace plus any of these characters [,]
[ \t,]+

# Bid/Offer spread
(?<Bid>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[ \t]*(?:/|-|\ )[ \t]*(?<Offer>[+|-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)

# Look for any other keywords in brackets (optional)
(?:

    # Skip over whitespace
    [ \t]*

    # <pattern>
    \(

    # Add words to word list
    (?<_KC8>(?:(?:\w|[ \t\\/]|\[\w*\])*?))

    # <pattern>
    \)
)?
```

Comment: what's that phrase about using a regex to solve a problem: now you have 2 problems?

Comment: I don't believe this problem could be solved any other way. If you can think of any other solution then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

If u are going to read from a file or something, better use a tool like awk to parse. Don't go for complex regex programs as they might cause issues in some less anticipated scenarios.
cheers!

Comment: Thanks but pattern matching is the correct solution for this problem. Its just that I don't know the few characters of regex that do what I need.

Comment: okay simon. If u are so sure, not a problem. But if u are sure of the way your input will be, then please do go and explore tools like awk. They will solve your problems within a line or two.